# Uniqueness of probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Suppose we have two (nondegenerate) probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$, $P$ and $\widetilde P$, such that for $X, Y \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} P$ and $\widetilde X, \widetilde Y \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \widetilde P$ $$X-Y \stackrel{d}{=} \widetilde X - \widetilde Y$$
where the equality is in distribution.  What can I say about the relationship between the two distributions $P$ and $\widetilde P$? Of course, they are not necessarily equal, since if we fix a distribution $P$, $X \sim P$ and let $\widetilde P$ be the law of $X+c$ for an arbitrary constant, then we have two different distributions (although trivially different) which satisfy the requirement.  Is this the only kind of difference possible?

For context: I am trying to give a rigorous proof of the general form of the characteristic function of a stable distribution, and I want to use this to go from the general form of a strictly stable ch.f. (which I have a rigorous proof of) to the general form of a non-strictly stable ch.f.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi$ denote the characteristic function of $P$ and $\widetilde{\varphi}$ that of $\widetilde P$. The characteristic function of $X-Y$ is
$$
t\mapsto \varphi(t)\varphi(-t)=\left\lvert \varphi(t)\right\rvert^2
$$
and that of
$X-Y$ is
$$
t\mapsto \widetilde{\varphi}(t)\widetilde{\varphi}(-t)=\left\lvert \widetilde{\varphi}(t)\right\rvert^2.
$$
Therefore, $X-Y \stackrel{d}{=} \widetilde X - \widetilde Y$ is equivalent to
$$\forall t\in\mathbb R, \quad \left\lvert \varphi(t)\right\rvert=\left\lvert \widetilde{\varphi}(t)\right\rvert.
$$

Comment: I know this part...but can anything be said about the imaginary part?  Specifically, if $$\varphi(t) = |\varphi(t)| e^{i y(t)}$$ and $$\widetilde \varphi(t) = |\varphi(t)| e^{i \widetilde y(t)}$$ what can we say about the functions $y$ and $\widetilde y$?

Comment: "I know this part..." Then it should have been a part of the opening post. I will think about the imaginary parts

Comment: Sure, I'll keep that in mind.  I figured that it might be understood based on the context I gave (the distribution of $X-Y$ where $X, Y \sim P$ for $P$ stable is a strictly stable distribution, which I have the general ch.f. of.  I want to pick an element, $\widetilde \phi$, from the general collection of ch.f.s which I want to prove are the only ch.f.s of stable distributions, with the same modulus as that of P's ch.f., and relate the imaginary parts).  Thanks for taking a look in the first place.

Comment: I have a feeling that the relationship between the imaginary parts is arbitrary though, but I am hopelessly lost.